# Sanitizing user input without converting to htmlentities

Tags: php, sanitization

How can I sanitize user input for a search query and still keep there data as is for example if a user enters `&` it wont be converted to `&amp;` and if a user enters `&amp;` it wont be converted to `&`?

Answer (score 4):

```
* use `mysql_real_escape_string()`
* Use `strip_tags()` to filter out unwanted HTML
* Escape all other output with `htmlspecialchars()`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying a MySQL database, I would recommend the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function. I don't think you should have too much of a problem. You can always convert characters back, but you want to ensure that you sanitize for the database when you query it.

Comment: can you give me an example of converting and deconverting?

Comment: you will want to use mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize a string for a mysql query. you will not have to desanitize it after you grab it from the database. you will also want to cast any numbers before you put it into a query - (int)$variable or (float)$variable. you will want to strip_tags() and variables that you print out onto your web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];

// escape username and password for use in SQL
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($pwd);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE
user='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pwd . "'"

// more code

mysql_close($con);
?>
```